# The use statement with non-compound name 'Session' has no effect

Tags: laravel

$ php artisan serve

ErrorException

The use statement with non-compound name 'Session' has no effect

at routes/web.php:6

```
  3▕ use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
  4▕ use Illuminate\Http\Request;
  5▕ use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
```

➜   6▕ use Session;
7▕

Comment: i don't need this:

use Session;

Answer (score 5):

The error says that doing `use Session` in the root namespace does not actually do anything because `Session` is already in the root namespace.

In reality `Session` does not exist in the root namespace but is rather an alias defined in [`config/app.php`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/app.php#L191). Bottom line is when you are in the root namespace already you don't need to do `use Session`.

While you don't need to do this, what I suggest you do is:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session
```

Alternatively you can use the session helper function:

```
session()
```

and you can also retrieve the session singleton using the application container:

```
app()->make('session');
```

This is just because personally I don't like global aliases. Your opinion may differ.